# How to call a function binding it to a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does jQuery provides a API to call functions binding the `this` variable to the jQuery object? E.g.:

```
function log() {
    console.log(this);
}

$('body').execute(log); // prints the $('body') object in the console
```

I know that this could be solved by making the log a plugin, but I don't want to do that because the function I need to call is generic and I don't want to tie it to jQuery.

### EDIT:

jQuery has no `execute` method, its just a snippet I added to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

### EDIT 2:

I am not asking how to workaround this problem (underscore.js bind already got me covered), I am only asking if jQuery already provides a similar API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this "without" having jQuery to implement anything, just "*flip*" things around a bit and use *function-name*`.apply (object, arguments)`

```
function func (arg1, arg2) {
   console.log ("ARG1: " + arg1);
   console.log ("ARG2: " + arg2);
   console.log ("using this: " + this.html ().length + "\n");
}

func.apply ($('body'), ['abc','123']);
func.apply ($('body')); // 2nd argument is optional
```

output

```
ARG1: abc
ARG2: 123
using this: 51645

ARG1: undefined
ARG2: undefined
using this: 51645
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that functions had a `html` property.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal we are passing in a jQuery object, it has `.html` - if that's what you are referring to?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Just as you are ignoring me in ##c++, I'll ignore you. ;-)

Comment: I am not ignoring you on IRC, except when you troll. Which is most of the time.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal If I'm online, I troll.. I troll here TWO, though it isn't as obvious as through IRC.

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't going to be what you want it to be in your scope. You can use an anonymous function with a parameter, though:

```
function log($this) {
    console.log($this);
}

$('body').execute(function() { log($(this)); }); // prints the $('body') object in the console
```

Comment: The question is "how do I make the call so that `this` _is_ what I want it to be in this scope?"

Comment: You guys are aware of the fact that `$('body').execute` isn't a valid property, even in jquery?

Comment: It's obviously a sample snippet trying to describe what kind of solution he is looking for, or well.. that's my interpretation, at least.

Comment: Yes, there is no "execute", I just just a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
    $.fn.prototype.execute = function() { 
      var f = function(){ console.log(this)};
     $.proxy( f   , this )()
    // that means something like 
    // f.call(this)   
   }
```

Assume , you have function:

```
var f= function( arg1, arg2){ 
  console.log(this, arg1, arg2)
}
```

There you call `f` passing context and arguments

```
 f.call(document.body, arg1,arg2);
```

or arguments as array by `apply` method

```
f.apply(document.body, [arg1,arg2]);
```

In both cases you will get

```
>> <body>...</body>, valOfarg1, varOfarg2
```